# How to resize a raster(image) in paper.js?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paperjs

I have loaded an image using the code from the **Paper.js** documentation. But I would like to change the image size. I don't want to scale the image but rather set dimensions to the image. Is there a way to set `width` and `height` of an image in **Paper.js**?

**JS**

```
var raster = new Raster({
    source: 'http://assets.paperjs.org/images/marilyn.jpg',
    position: view.center
});
```

Comment: have you tried the `scale` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such method by default in the **Paper.js** Raster documentation. This won't prevent you from adding your own though. You can do the following:

```
/**
 * Re-scales the Raster object to the new dimensions.
 * Method added to the Raster's prototype to easily
 * call it from the raster object itself.
 */
Raster.prototype.rescale = function(width, height) {
    this.scale(width / this.width, height / this.height);
};

var raster = new Raster({
    source: 'http://assets.paperjs.org/images/marilyn.jpg',
    position: view.center
});

raster.rescale(200, 100);
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/glouhaichi/pen/ZaOxNm) with a working example.

Comment: Actually, this might be an alternative to what I asked. Thanks, one last thing is there a way to reduce opacity gradually.

Comment: How gradually? If you want you can ask a new question or edit this one and let me know with a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can scale the image to fit canvas via:

```
const image = new paper.Raster('http://assets.paperjs.org/images/marilyn.jpg');
const widthRatioOfCanvasToImage =
  paper.view.bounds.width / image.bounds.width;
const heightRatioOfCanvasToImage =
  paper.view.bounds.height / image.bounds.height;
const scale = Math.min(
  widthRatioOfCanvasToImage,
  heightRatioOfCanvasToImage
);
image.scale(scale, scale);
```